# SMC New Zealand, Job Search Visa or Resident Visa

Tags: immigration, new-zealand, skilled-migration

I am planning to start SMC application for New Zealand. I have 165 marks where i hold a MSC and over 14 years of work experience.

Recently i learnt that they offer a job search visa before granting residence visa.

1. Is job search visa the only way or is there a chance that we get residence visa directly?
2. If i am granted a job search visa, what are the options i have to take my family with me?
3. What are the options for kids education while i am under job search visa? (should i apply for child student visa?)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get a residence visa directly. If you have enough points for your Expression of Interest, then you will be offered an invitation to apply. You do not need to have a job offer before applying, but you are expected to be looking for a job. If I remember correctly, there is some initial period of time after you are granted a residence visa where they make sure you still actually have a job.

In the list of [All visa options to work](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/work/all-work-visas), I don't see anything like a "job search visa". There isn't much need for one anyway, because you can look for a job while on a visitor visa (NZeTA). You can apply for a new visa (whether it is a temporary work visa or a residence visa) without having to leave New Zealand, as long as you do not exceed your time allowed on your current visa (3 months for NZeTA).

(I see that some time in the past there was a [Silver Fern Job Search Work Visa](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/apply-for-a-visa/visa-factsheet/silver-fern-job-search-work-visa), but that visa "has permanently closed and will not reopen".)